# QwtPlot - Multiple Y Axis

Tags: qt, qwt

I use QwtPlot 6.1.3.

Is there any way to display multiple curves, sharing a single X axis, but each one with its own Y axis ?

I didn't find anything in the documentation, and my Google searchs didn't return anything usefull (just some hacks)

Something similar to this :

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Qwt doesn't supports multiple axis attached to the same Canvas, it has however a fork that supports:

https://sourceforge.net/p/qwt/code/HEAD/tree/branches/qwt-6.1-multiaxes/

Comment: Thanks. Is there any example available of how to use it ?

Comment: sorry, I don't know about any example, I actually created my library from scratch so I wouldn't depend on Qwt for multi plotting.